# Mint: Connect to Raspberry Pi via SSH while connected to ProtonVPN (and vice versa)

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I connect to my Raspberry Pi 4b via SSH from my Linux Mint 21.2 PC. However, while connected to ProtonVPN CLI I can't connect via SSH, I get the error `ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi: Name or service not known`

How can I connect via SSH while also connected to the VPN?

Also, how can I do the reverse. I'd like to [install ProtonVPN on the Pi](https://raspberrytips.com/protonvpn-on-raspberry-pi/) and then still be able to connect via SSH.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need static routes between your two hosts and a way to avoid a global DNS lookup of the hostname.

The immediate error you are seeing (`Could not resolve hostname rapsberrypi`) is coming from Proton's DNS servers because they don't know the IP address of your Raspberry Pi -- and shouldn't, it's not a fully-qualified domain name (FQDN). You could bypass that error by trying to SSH to the IP address of your Raspberry Pi, but that would likely give a new error (`No route to host`) because it likely has a private IP address (RFC 1918). In which case, in order to establish a network route between the two hosts, you need to ensure that the VPN connection is not used by defining a static route from the SSH client to the SSH server.

Without any static routes defined, all network traffic will use the default route. And when you establish your VPN connection, your default route is updated from your local router to your VPN's router. Additionally, the VPN connection is updating the DNS server(s) used to look up hostnames. So a connection that normally uses a DNS server on the local router and a default route through the local router becomes a connection that uses the VPN DNS servers and a default route through the VPN router after establishing the VPN connection.

But you can tell your local host which router to use when connecting to a specific IP address by defining a static route for that IP address. So if you define a static route on your Linux Mint host specifying your local router for the IP address of the Raspberry Pi, then you can SSH to the IP address of the Raspberry Pi and the connection will stay on the local network instead of using the VPN.

If you use OpenVPN to connect to Proton, you can configure a static route for a specific host with an option like (be sure to replace `192.168.1.101` with the IP of your Raspberry Pi):

```
route 192.168.1.101 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
```

Alternatively, you can configure a static route for your entire local network with this option (presuming your local network is `192.168.1.0/24`):

```
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 net_gateway
```

This configuration option is a wrapper for the `route` command with a special value `net_gateway` that refers to the default route that existed before the VPN connection was established, [documented here](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/).

That static route only allows the SSH connection (or any other connection) if you are connecting directly to the IP address. In order to connect with a friendly name, we need to translate that name into an IP address without using the VPN. An easy way to do this is with a host entry in your SSH client configuration (`~/.ssh/config`) so that the name lookup doesn't need DNS at all:

```
Host raspberrypi
    HostName 192.168.1.101
```

With this approach, you will need to update the configuration file if/when the IP address changes on your Raspberry Pi, so you might want to configure the DHCP server on your local router to always give it the same IP address.

Another approach could be to install a local DNS server such as `dnsmasq` on your Linux Mint host to intelligently direct some DNS queries to your local router while sending the rest to your VPN DNS servers; but running a local DNS server to support a single SSH connection might lead to a [shark attack](https://xkcd.com/349/).

Comment: I already have the router set to always give the device the same IP, so I realized I could just ssh using the IP instead of the host name and then it works. I'm not sure if that is what you meant, but I appreciate the thorough explanation!

Comment: +1 This is a good and clear answer. :)